# .Net how to detect if built-in exception is thrown manually via code in executing assembly

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

In my code there are lot of areas where we manually "throw" InvalidOperationException. We have specifc handlers for handling this exception type. However there is a requirement that we have to write some logic based on the fact if the exception came beacuse of a **throw** or it came from the system. Below is the example:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
                //throwFirstLayer(); //if i uncomment this i am throwing the error manually
                var people = new List<Person>();

                people.Add(new Person("John", "Doe"));
                people.Add(new Person("Jane", "Doe"));
                people.Sort(); //Suppose in this line system throws InvalidOp exception
                foreach (var person in people)
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", person.FirstName, person.LastName);
            }
            
            catch(InvalidOperationException ioex)
            {
                var e = ioex;
            }
}

public static void throwFirstLayer()
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("manual");
        }

 public class Person
    {
        public Person(String fName, String lName)
        {
            FirstName = fName;
            LastName = lName;
        }

        public String FirstName { get; set; }
        public String LastName { get; set; }
    }
```

here inside the catch block i want to detect if the exception had been **thrown** by me manually from the code or the system raised it due to an actual invalid operation?

Comment: Please could you edit your post to fix the indentation? It's somewhat all over the place at the moment, causing unnecessarily scrolling and making it harder to read.

Comment: Every exception originates from a throw. Perhaps you mean whether or not it is a throw in your own code or a throw in some other assembly (system or 3rd party)?

Comment: Exactly @KlausGütter

Answer (score 4):

you should first create your own exception class:

```cs
   public class MyInvalidOperationException : Exception
   {

   }
```

and throw your custom exception when you need to. (manual ones)

```cs
throw new MyInvalidOperationException();
```

Comment: I know changing the exception class is the best option, but then in the current solution i have to make changes in a lot of areas which i am trying to avoid.

Comment: Then your application design contains a fundamental flaw. I would consider investing the necessary time to correct it and then move on with a more robust design implementation from there on. It will pay dividends further along the development path of your application.

Comment: simply use an IDE to replace all files. vscode example => CTRL+SHIF+F(find in files) `throw new InvalidOperationException(` To `throw new MyInvalidOperationException(`.
there is no other clean way @RyanDotnet

Comment: @AliReza..Request you to please read and understand the question before answering  which will save both of our times :) . The question is if there is any way to detect whether the exception is thrown from my code or from any system/external libraries.

Answer (score 4):

You *could* examine the stack trace of the exception and see where it originated from - but that's slow, and error-prone in production due to JIT optimizations.

I would question the wisdom of a design that needs this in the first place, but if you really, really, really need to do so, I'd suggest creating your own specific class derived from `InvalidOperationException` - make sure you only ever throw that (rather than plain `InvalidOperationException`), and then you can check whether any given instance has a concrete type that is your custom exception type or not.

Comment: Thanks Jon. I know changing the exception class is the best option, but then in the current solution i have to make changes in a lot of areas which i am trying to avoid.

Comment: @RyanDotnet: The best option would be to avoid a design that requires this at all - I would *at least* insist on making sure that the implementation of the dodgy design isn't done in a brittle way.